# Showing text from data-content attribute

Tags: wordpress, mobile, tooltip

I am wondering if it's possible to display text that is already in the data-content attribute within an a tag without hover?

I have text in a tooltip that I need to output on mobile without the hover effect so that users can see it. The problem is it is built in already in a parent theme and on mobile, the text inside the tooltip does not display.

```
<a href="#" class="tooltips" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-content="My text that I want to display on mobile" data-original-title="" title="">
    <img src="image">
</a>
```

For reference as to what I mean, see this link: [Link to tooltip icons](http://vaughansnowremoval.ca/cart/)

Comment: Sure, it's possible. You can either edit your template file and write a CSS media query to hide the content for desktop devices, or you can control the hide/show using JavaScript. That said, this question is too broad, as asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bootstrap (as I assume your wordpress theme is based on) it would be

```js
$('.tooltips').tooltip({
    title: function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-content')
    }    
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/bozyh4co/**